# Solving Boolean expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can anybody help me to solve the below expression.
A'B'C+A'BC+AB'C+A'BC'+AB'C=AB'+A'B+BC
I'm so lost just been trying to get it for awhile only using the 10 boolean simplification rules.

Comment: What did you try? How far did you get? Where did you get stuck? Please post some of your own efforts, incomplete as they may be.

Comment: A'B'C+A'BC+AB'C+A'BC'+AB'C=A'B'C+A'BC+AB'C+A'BC'=B'C(A'+A)+A'B(C+C')=B'C+A'B   My answer is coming like this

Comment: Well, you did that completely correct ... that original expression is indeed equivalent to B'C+A'B ... but *not* to AB' + A'B +BC ... so ... are you sure you have the original expressin correct?  Or the goal expression?

Comment: Yes the original expression is this  A'B'C+A'BC+AB'C+A'BC'+AB'C=AB'+A'B+BC   How to prove it?

Comment: You can't!  As I said, they are not equivalent, and what's not true you cannot prove. Sorry, but math needs to have some standards of decency.